# Unable to download signingReport for SHA1 and SHA-256

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, hash, firebase-authentication

I had to change the project name of Android Studio App but due to this Phone verification stopped working. As this was asking for SHA1 and SHA-256 Hash keys and when I came to find SigningReport from Gradle Panel and It showing an error.

By the way, app installation is working fine. Other login mechanisms are working fine like: Custom Email Login, Google Login, Facebook Login.

I need to know what went wrong?

I used these steps to change project Name as Mentioned on this site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-change-the-project-name-in-android-studio/

Error Message:

D:\PK\New folder\Trail\My APP>gradlew signingReport
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Configuration cache is an incubating feature.
Calculating task graph as no configuration cache is available for tasks: signingReport

115 problems were found storing the configuration cache, 4 of which seem unique.

- Task `:app:signingReport` of type `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.SigningReportTask`: cannot serialize object of type 'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfig
  uration', a subtype of 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration', as these are not supported with the configuration cache.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:disallowed_types
- Task `:app:signingReport` of type `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.SigningReportTask`: cannot serialize object of type 'org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject', a subtype of
  'org.gradle.api.Project', as these are not supported with the configuration cache.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:disallowed_types
- Task `:app:signingReport` of type `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.SigningReportTask`: cannot serialize object of type 'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfig
  urationContainer', a subtype of 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.ConfigurationContainer', as these are not supported with the configuration cache.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:disallowed_types
- Task `:app:signingReport` of type `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.SigningReportTask`: value 'flatmap(provider(class com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkComponentsBuildService))' fa
  iled to unpack provider

See the complete report at file:///D:/PK/New%20folder/Trail/Exam%20String/build/reports/configuration-cache/ab9kk6ntb87qv1nszinvkztgv/configuration-cache-report.html

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'components' from type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.SigningReportTask': error writing value of type 'com.google.common.collect.
  RegularImmutableList'

> Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'elements' from type 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList$SerializedForm': error writing value of type '[Ljava.lang.Object;'
> Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'androidTest' from type 'com.android.build.api.variant.impl.ApplicationVariantImpl': error writing value of type 'com.android.build.ap
> i.component.impl.AndroidTestImpl'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'delegate$delegate' from type 'com.android.build.api.component.impl.AndroidTestImpl': error writing value of type 'kotlin.Synchroni
> zedLazyImpl'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'value' from type 'kotlin.InitializedLazyImpl': error writing value of type 'com.android.build.api.component.impl.AndroidTestCre
> ationConfigImpl'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'globalScope' from type 'com.android.build.api.component.impl.AndroidTestCreationConfigImpl': error writing value of type 'co
> m.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.GlobalScope'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'extension' from type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.GlobalScope': error writing value of type 'com.android.buil
> d.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'applicationVariants' from type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension': error writing value of
> type 'org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectSet'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'store' from type 'org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectSet': error writing value of type 'org.gradle.api.inte
> rnal.collections.IterationOrderRetainingSetElementSource'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'inserted' from type 'org.gradle.api.internal.collections.IterationOrderRetainingSetElementSource': error writing
> value of type 'java.util.ArrayList'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'cache' from type 'org.gradle.api.internal.collections.AbstractIterationOrderRetainingElementSource$Element':
> error writing value of type 'java.util.ArrayList'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'testVariant' from type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl': error writing value
> of type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.TestVariantImpl'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'variantData' from type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.TestVariantImpl': error writing value of
> type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.TestVariantData'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'testedVariantData' from type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.TestVariantData': error writ
> ing value of type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'artifacts' from type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData': error wr
> iting value of type 'com.android.build.api.artifact.impl.ArtifactsImpl'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'storageProvider' from type 'com.android.build.api.artifact.impl.ArtifactsImpl': error writing
> value of type 'com.android.build.api.artifact.impl.StorageProviderImpl'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'directory' from type 'com.android.build.api.artifact.impl.StorageProviderImpl': error writi
> ng value of type 'com.android.build.api.artifact.impl.TypedStorageProvider'
> > Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'singleStorage' from type 'com.android.build.api.artifact.impl.TypedStorageProvider': err
> or writing value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap'
> > java.util.ConcurrentModificationException (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Configuration cache entry discarded with 115 problems.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answer Found, It was happening due to

org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true

It has to be false to get SHA Hash keys.

and

For faster build up process it needs to be true.

It can also be enabled persistently in a gradle.properties file that you can check into source control:

Answer (score 0):

**check in the gradle.properties file and make the properties**

```
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=false
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).